# How to read XML file data with Php?

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I have xml file in the following format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">  
  <channel>  
  <title>Data feed Title</title>
  <link>http://www.amarchitrakatha.com/in/</link>
  <description>Data feed description.</description>
    <item>ACKKALID0577
    <g:id><![CDATA[ACKKALID0577]]></g:id>
    <title><![CDATA[Kalidasa]]></title>
    <link><![CDATA[http://www.amarchitrakatha.com/in/kalidasa?fee=19&fep=1147]]></link>
    <g:price>70.00</g:price>
    <g:sale_price></g:sale_price>
    <description><![CDATA[Kalidas Owes His Fame To His Sanksrit Play Abhijnana-Shakuntala (Shakuntala Recognised By The Token Ring), The Long Epic Poem Kumara-Sambhava (Birth Of Kumara) And The Lyric Poem Meghaduta (Cloud Messenger). Kalidasa, Who Lived Some Time In The Middle Of The 4Th And Early 5Th Centuries A.D., Has Left No Account Of His Life. According To Popular Legend, He Owed His Ingenuity As Much To Goddess Kaliâ€™S Blessings As To His Own Talents.]]></description>
    <g:product_type><![CDATA[Amar Chitra Katha  > Visionaries > Singles]]></g:product_type>
    <g:google_product_category><![CDATA[]]></g:google_product_category>
    <g:image_link><![CDATA[http://www.amarchitrakatha.com/media/catalog/product/K/A/KALIDASA_0__5.jpg]]></g:image_link>
    <g:condition>new</g:condition>
    <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
    <g:shipping_weight>0.09 kg</g:shipping_weight>
    <g:brand><![CDATA[]]></g:brand>
    <g:mpn><![CDATA[ACKKALID0577]]></g:mpn>
    <g:gtin><![CDATA[]]></g:gtin>
  </item>
  <item>ACKPRITH1413
    <g:id><![CDATA[ACKPRITH1413]]></g:id>
    <title><![CDATA[Prithviraj Chauhan]]></title>
    <link><![CDATA[http://www.amarchitrakatha.com/in/prithviraj-chauhan?fee=19&fep=1150]]></link>
    <g:price>70.00</g:price>
    <g:sale_price></g:sale_price>
    <description><![CDATA[Jaichand Was Furious! His Daughter Samyogita Had Eloped With Prithviraj Chauhan, The Warrior King Of Delhi. She, Like Many Others, Was Smitten By Tales Of His Daring, His Nobility And His Sense Of Honour. Though The Young Coupleâ€™S Happiness Was Doomed, Even In His Dying Hour, It Was The Brave Prithviraj Who Chose How His Life Should End.]]></description>
    <g:product_type><![CDATA[Amar Chitra Katha  > Brave Hearts Story > Singles]]></g:product_type>
    <g:google_product_category><![CDATA[]]></g:google_product_category>
    <g:image_link><![CDATA[http://www.amarchitrakatha.com/media/catalog/product/P/R/PRITHVIRAJ_CHAUHAN_0__4.jpg]]></g:image_link>
    <g:condition>new</g:condition>
    <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
    <g:shipping_weight>0.09 kg</g:shipping_weight>
    <g:brand><![CDATA[]]></g:brand>
    <g:mpn><![CDATA[ACKPRITH1413]]></g:mpn>
    <g:gtin><![CDATA[]]></g:gtin>
  </item>
 </channel>
</rss>
```

By using `simplexml_load_file` I am not getting data of item. How to parse this type of format XML with PHP? I want to get the data of all items like g:id, title, link etc.

```
if (file_exists('Sample.xml')) {
$xml = simplexml_load_file('Sample.xml');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml->channel);
echo '</pre>';
} else {
exit('Failed to open Sample.xml.');
}
```

And m getting result as

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[title] => Data feed Title
[link] => http://www.amarchitrakatha.com/in/
[description] => Data feed description.
[item] => Array
    (
        [0] => ACKKALID0577

        [1] => ACKPRITH1413
    )
)
```

I have to store data of items in specific variables.

Comment: what's your php version?

Comment: You've included your XML, but not the code you're trying to use to import it. Can you please include your code, along with a more precise description of your results? "Not getting data of item" could be any of a number of things. Check your error log, include anything suspicious [in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43464051/edit). While you're at it, you might want to include a more complete description of what you want to do with your results; the best direction is usually determined by knowing your destination. :)

Comment: I have edited code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, tested!

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://example.com/rss.xml');
$namespaces = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
var_dump($namespaces);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
    ["g"]=> string(29) "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"
}
```

Then:

```
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) 
{ 
    // for php >= 5.2.0
    // $id = (string) $item->children('g', TRUE)->id; 
    // for php < 5.2.0
    // $id = (string) $item->children('http://base.google.com/ns/1.0')->id; 
    $id = (string) $item->children($namespaces["g"])->id; // for php < 5.2.0
    $title = (string) $item->title; 
    $link  = (string) $item->link; 
    var_dump($id, $title, $link); 
    echo "--\n"; 
}
```

Output:

```
string(12) "ACKKALID0577"
string(8) "Kalidasa"
string(58) "http://www.amarchitrakatha.com/in/kalidasa?fee=19&fep=1147"
--
string(12) "ACKPRITH1413"
string(18) "Prithviraj Chauhan"
string(68) "http://www.amarchitrakatha.com/in/prithviraj-chauhan?fee=19&fep=1150"
--
```

Finally, for e.g. in order to bind the results to an array of objects:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://example.com/rss.xml');
$namespaces = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
$itemArray = array();
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) 
{ 
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->id = (string) $item->children($namespaces["g"])->id; // for php < 5.2.0
    $obj->title = (string) $item->title; 
    $obj->link  = (string) $item->link; 
    $itemArray[] = $obj;
} 
var_dump($itemArray);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (3) {
        ["id"]=> string(12) "ACKKALID0577"
        ["title"]=> string(8) "Kalidasa"
        ["link"]=> string(58) "http://www.amarchitrakatha.com/in/kalidasa?fee=19&fep=1147"
    }
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#3 (3) {
        ["id"]=> string(12) "ACKPRITH1413"
        ["title"]=> string(18) "Prithviraj Chauhan"
        ["link"]=> string(68) "http://www.amarchitrakatha.com/in/prithviraj-chauhan?fee=19&fep=1150"
    }
}
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getnamespaces.php

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php

Ref: [http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?606057-...](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?606057-Parsing-RSS-feed-issue-(google-base-namespace-))

Answer (score 1):

you can get loop the values inside the g: attribute using this

```
$handle_object = $element->children('g', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe with this xml style you can use the standard PHP xml parser (i.e. https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php)
Load it into your variable (i.e. $xml)
Then read these nodes like so:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($yourXMLFile)
$xml->children('g', true)->id;
```

(the above will pull all instances of <g:id> )

Not tested my end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PHP` `DOMDocument` for getting it done. As i have done in the below code.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/778136)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$object= new DOMDocument();
$object->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">  
  <channel>  
  <title>Data feed Title</title>
  <link>http://www.amarchitrakatha.com/in/</link>
  <description>Data feed description.</description>
    <item>ACKKALID0577
    <g:id><![CDATA[ACKKALID0577]]></g:id>
    <title><![CDATA[Kalidasa]]></title>
    <link><![CDATA[http://www.amarchitrakatha.com/in/kalidasa?fee=19&fep=1147]]></link>
    <g:price>70.00</g:price>
    <g:sale_price></g:sale_price>
    <description><![CDATA[Kalidas Owes His Fame To His Sanksrit Play Abhijnana-Shakuntala (Shakuntala Recognised By The Token Ring), The Long Epic Poem Kumara-Sambhava (Birth Of Kumara) And The Lyric Poem Meghaduta (Cloud Messenger). Kalidasa, Who Lived Some Time In The Middle Of The 4Th And Early 5Th Centuries A.D., Has Left No Account Of His Life. According To Popular Legend, He Owed His Ingenuity As Much To Goddess Kaliâ€™S Blessings As To His Own Talents.]]></description>
    <g:product_type><![CDATA[Amar Chitra Katha  > Visionaries > Singles]]></g:product_type>
    <g:google_product_category><![CDATA[]]></g:google_product_category>
    <g:image_link><![CDATA[http://www.amarchitrakatha.com/media/catalog/product/K/A/KALIDASA_0__5.jpg]]></g:image_link>
    <g:condition>new</g:condition>
    <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
    <g:shipping_weight>0.09 kg</g:shipping_weight>
    <g:brand><![CDATA[]]></g:brand>
    <g:mpn><![CDATA[ACKKALID0577]]></g:mpn>
    <g:gtin><![CDATA[]]></g:gtin>
  </item>
  <item>ACKPRITH1413
    <g:id><![CDATA[ACKPRITH1413]]></g:id>
    <title><![CDATA[Prithviraj Chauhan]]></title>
    <link><![CDATA[http://www.amarchitrakatha.com/in/prithviraj-chauhan?fee=19&fep=1150]]></link>
    <g:price>70.00</g:price>
    <g:sale_price></g:sale_price>
    <description><![CDATA[Jaichand Was Furious! His Daughter Samyogita Had Eloped With Prithviraj Chauhan, The Warrior King Of Delhi. She, Like Many Others, Was Smitten By Tales Of His Daring, His Nobility And His Sense Of Honour. Though The Young Coupleâ€™S Happiness Was Doomed, Even In His Dying Hour, It Was The Brave Prithviraj Who Chose How His Life Should End.]]></description>
    <g:product_type><![CDATA[Amar Chitra Katha  > Brave Hearts Story > Singles]]></g:product_type>
    <g:google_product_category><![CDATA[]]></g:google_product_category>
    <g:image_link><![CDATA[http://www.amarchitrakatha.com/media/catalog/product/P/R/PRITHVIRAJ_CHAUHAN_0__4.jpg]]></g:image_link>
    <g:condition>new</g:condition>
    <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
    <g:shipping_weight>0.09 kg</g:shipping_weight>
    <g:brand><![CDATA[]]></g:brand>
    <g:mpn><![CDATA[ACKPRITH1413]]></g:mpn>
    <g:gtin><![CDATA[]]></g:gtin>
  </item>
 </channel>
</rss>');
$tagValues=array("g:id","title","link");
$result=array();
foreach($object->getElementsByTagName("item") as $item)
{
    foreach($item->childNodes as $node)
    {
        if($node instanceof DOMElement)
        {
            if(in_array( $node->tagName,$tagValues))
            {
                $result[$node->tagName][]=$node->textContent;
            }
        }
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: It's giving result but i have to store data in specific variables.

Comment: @Cvince Okay no issues i am updating my post , in seconds

Comment: @Cvince Check my post now and have a look on `Try this code snippet` You can check there after this you can use `extract` as well.